# Plugin broken after updating jQuery to 1.4.2

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've written a jQuery plugin and it was working well for all version up to 1.4.1. Now that jQuery was updated to 1.4.2 is stopped working entirely. I have a bunch of unit tests and in last version only 32 of 300+ pass.

I have checked 1.4.2 changelog but all it says is that there were some performance improvements and that's it.

Here's the changelog:

```
Performance Improvements:
· The performance of calling .bind() and .unbind().
· The performance of .empty(), .remove(), and .html().
· The performance of inserting a single DOM node into a document.
· The performace of calling $("body").

Bug Fixes:
· Remove existing foo[] when traditional = false in param.
· Problem with getJSON callback does not firing.
· Removed the Need for setArray.
```

I don't use any of the parts mentioned in bug fixes section. Were there any other changes in this version that could break my code? I don't really know where to start debugging.

My plugin code is available [here](http://stuff.rajchel.pl/jec/jquery.jec.js) and failing unit tests can be found [here](http://stuff.rajchel.pl/jec/tests/). Once again changing jQuery to 1.4.1 makes all unit tests to pass.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when trying to use the plugin? What kind of tests fail?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors/warnings. I've tested both unit tests and plugin itself against JSLint in order to find that there are no missing semicolons or other problems. In most browsers almost all test fail. It's a little better in IE but still the plugin is not usable. I noticed that mostly tests that remove plugin functionality are still ok but it's probably because those features are not enabled correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to check places where you call `$.data()` to retrieve value - it now returns `null` or `undefined` as I tested while mu plug-in stopped to work.

Comment: No I don't think that's the case. It was returning `undefined` before and it does so now.

Comment: On the second thought, it's not exactly the problem but it's close. I was using `$.data()` instead of `$(selector).data()` and second method returns `null` if the value does not exists.